# Mongo C # driver : All data is not returned when using inheritance with subdocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, inheritance, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongodb with inheritance. I can query the data for each inherited object successfully with the c # driver until I add a subDocument. When I query Document1 the SubDocument1 is null but the base object has the data for ElementA, ElementB and the SubDocumentBase  as I expect.

If I leave the BsonIgnoreExtraElements attribute off of the SubDocumentBase class I get a deserializing error because it is looking for the elementC element which may be null depending on the inherited object I am querying. There may me something wrong with the way I have my classes structured. An help would be appreciated.

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Document1>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetDiscriminator("MyDiscriminator");
        });

        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("myDb");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("myCollection");
        var query = collection.AsQueryable<DocumentBase>().OfType<Document1>();

[CollectionName("myCollection")]
public abstract class DocumentBase
{
    [BsonElement("elementA")]
    public DateTime ElementA { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("elementB")]
    public DateTime ElementB { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("subDocument")]
    public SubDocumentBase SubDocumentBase { get; set; }

}
public class Document1 : DocumentBase
{
    public SubDocument1 SubDocument1 { get; set; }
}

public class SubDocument1 : SubDocumentBase
{
    [BsonElement("elementC")]
    public string ElementC { get; set; }
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class SubDocumentBase
{
    [BsonElement("subElementA")]
    public string SubElementA { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("subElementB")]
    public string SubElementB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which C# MongoDB driver version are you using?

Comment: @thepirat000 it is v1.11.0.92

Answer (score 0):

I moved the BsonElement from the base class. To the derived class.

```
        [CollectionName("myCollection")]
        public abstract class DocumentBase
        {
            [BsonElement("elementA")]
            public DateTime ElementA { get; set; }

            [BsonElement("elementB")]
            public DateTime ElementB { get; set; }

            // I moved this to the SubDocument1 property
            [BsonElement("subDocument")]
            public SubDocumentBase SubDocumentBase { get; set; }

        }
        public class Document1 : DocumentBase
        {
            // I moved BsonElement here
            [BsonElement("subDocument")]
            public SubDocument1 SubDocument1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class SubDocument1 : SubDocumentBase
        {
            [BsonElement("elementC")]
            public string ElementC { get; set; }
        }

        [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
        public class SubDocumentBase
        {
            [BsonElement("subElementA")]
            public string SubElementA { get; set; }

            [BsonElement("subElementB")]
            public string SubElementB { get; set; }
        }
```